# Gunicorn preload config parameter not working

Tags: python, gunicorn

My `config.py` file for gunicorn looks like that:

```
preload = True
loglevel = "debug"
```

I run gunicorn with the following command:

```
gunicorn -c config.py --bind 0.0.0.0:1234 app.index:server
```

The log looks like this:

```
service   |      preload: False
```

**Why is the preload parameter not showing up in the config print out when starting?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short answer:** because of a typo: `preload_app` is correct, not `preload`.

**Longer answer:** While in the command line, the preload parameter is `--preload`, in the `config.py` it needs to be called `preload_app` instead of `preload`:

```
preload_app = True
```

Now the log looks as expected:

```
service   |      preload: True
```